# Finding if a value exists in either table

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

I have two tables, tblONE and tblTWO. I wish to find if the value stored in `Object.Name` exists in either of them. I have tried the following command:

```
            SQLCmd.CommandText = "SELECT Count(ID) FROM tblONE WHERE ID = '" & Object.Name & "' UNION ALL SELECT Count(ID) FROM tblTWO WHERE ID = '" & Object.Name & "'"
```

However, only the first SELECT appears to be executed.

Comment: Please add input and expected output

Comment: What makes you say that only the first is executed?

Comment: Are you sure the value exists in both tables?

Comment: @zip the value only exists in ONE table at a time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative would be,

```
'Any of them contains the record?

SELECT
    count(*)
FROM
    tblONE left join tblTwo on tblOne.Id = tblTwo.Id ' or just tblOne, tblTwo
Where
    tblOne.Id = @id OR tblTwo.Id =@id;



'Which tale contains the Id?

Select
   T.fromTable
From
(
    SELECT Id, "Table1" as fromTable FROM tblONE Where tblOne.Id = @id;
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Id, "Table2" as fromTable FROM tblTwo Where tblTwo.Id = @id;
) T ' if both tables has the row, you get multiple rows.
```

Comment: Should be a FULL JOIN instead

Answer (score 0):

Here is one method.  It checks first in `tblONE` and then in `tblTWO`:

```
SELECT IIF(Count(*) > 0, 1,
           (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblTWO WHERE ID = @ID) 
          )   
FROM tblONE
WHERE ID = @ID;
```

Or another alternative:

```
select iif(t1.cnt1 + t2.cnt2 > 0, 1, 0) as is present
from (select count(*) as cnt1
      from tblONE
      where id = @id
     ) as t1,  -- have to use , because MS Access does not support CROSS JOIN
     (select count(*) as cnt2
      from tblTWO
      where id = @id
     ) as t2
```

Comment: `IIF` expressions may not directly work with aggregates and/or subqueries. Access may complain expression should be in `GROUP BY`.

Comment: @Parfait . . . I know MS Access is finicky.  It always suprises me how much.  I offered another solution that should be quite acceptable to Access.